# Config proxy in the terminal

Tags: macos, networking, terminal, proxy

I am trying to download a source code from assembla in mac machine. I had a open network before so i just used the

```
git clone git@git.assembla.com:myproject.git
```

in the terminal to download the source code. Now proxy has been set in the network. When i try to download the code ,it is not hitting the proxy (My network admin say). So is there a way i should set the proxy in the terminal to download the code.

I have web proxy server: proxy.xomanyname.com and port:80 .

Please help to download the source code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this from your terminal:

> export http_proxy=http://proxy.xomanyname.com:80/

You can find detailed proxy settings here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Proxy_settings